# Naming convention in Java libraries and projects

Tags: java, shared-libraries, naming-conventions

The suggestion [Creating a java library with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213871/creating-a-java-library-with-eclipse) was very helpful. I created a library project, exported it to a JAR file, and added to the build path of a couple of clients.

What names will be better if each library may be used by several clients and vice versa?

For instance.

**For projects.**

- com.rp.project1
- com.rp.project2
- com.rp.project3

and so on.

**For libraries.**

- com.rp.lib1
- com.rp.lib2
- com.rp.lib3

and so on.

Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are no naming conventions for libraries and projects. You are allowed to call them as you like.

Important is that you use the right names for packages. They should be unique! For example use your email address.

You get a quick overview of naming conventions [here](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

*Possible duplicated many times!*

Comment: thanks. Let practice demonstrate